# Series current Feedback

Tags: amplifier, jfet, common-emitter, negative-feedback

I was tryig to build this circuit ("Series-feedback pair") from "Art of electronics" book (p. 150).

[image]

Since I do not have the exact components I tried to model it in LTSpice with what I have and ended up with this circuit (the resistor have non-standart values as I will anyway will have to adjust them upon trying this out on the breadboard), where the darligton pair I added when I could not achieve the desirable level of open-loop gain:

[image]

Although this circuit does the job, but to achieve the desired performance I had to fine tune by hand some resistor values. For example when I change Rs to 500 Ohm or 3kOhm the circuit does not work anymore, clipping either for positive swing or for negative swing.

And also, since I was building it stage-by-stage, after adding a feedback, the operating point had shifted significantly, so I had to readjust it almost from scratch.

**My question is:**

**Is there a more-or-less standart procedure for designing such or more complex feedback circuits or is the manual tweaking the only way? Since when complexity would increase these adjustments will take quite a bit of time.**

I tried to google about it for a while, but could not find any description, other than for simple CE amplifiers.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why didn't you simulate it with the values and components originally shown in AOE?

Comment: because I dont have these trasistors, so I thought I have no possibility to match the simulation with my breadboard struggles. Also I find it usefull to check my understanding by building circuits on same principles, but with different parameters.

Comment: Start from a known good place and establish that first. Then move on with component changes.

Comment: Not all of them exist in LTSPICE (at least I could not find). I also always try to build the circuit I model. Anyway the main question is not as much about this very circuit, but more general, where this is used as an example.